# how to map two dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have two `excel` files

```
+ File one contains specific data about different customer (like: Sex, Age, Name...) and 
+ File two contains different transactions for each customer
```

I want to create a new Column in `File2` containing specific data to each Costumer from `File1`

Comment: Both the dataframes have a common row, correct? Like customer id

Comment: ```pandas.DataFrame.join``` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Comment: Yes, join or pandas.DataFrame.merge (which is more powerfull, but actually the same if you don't have to deal with indexes while joining).

Comment: #Ninad Gaikwad Yes both df have the same Costumer_ID column

Comment: @Ninad Gaikwad,  yes

Comment: @jottbe  I tried **join, **merge, **Append, **concat .... they are not working, because I need to allocate to each Costumer his SEX and AGE every time he appears in the File 2

Comment: @ShahineGreene, could you give some sample data?

Comment: @ShahineGreene that's what merge and join usually do. But without your data, everything is just plain guessing... It's not even clear, what column[s] can be used to combine the two data frames

Comment: @politicalscientist I really want to share a sample of the data

Comment: @ShahineGreene, ok so read your files as dataframes and use `.to_clipboard()` method to update your original post with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same as @jc416 but using `pd.merge`:

```
file2.merge(file1, on='customer_id')
```

---

```
    transaction_id  customer_id  amount     sex  age    name
0   12h2j4hk        af4wf3       123.2      m    12     mike
1   12h2j4h1        af4wf3       5.22       m    12     mike
2   12h2j4h3        af4wf3       1.2        m    12     mike
3   12h2j4h6        af4wf3       999.3      m    12     mike
4   12h2j4h2        z20ask       13.2       f    15     sam
5   12h2j4h4        z20ask       2341.12    f    15     sam
6   12h2j4h5        z20ask       235.96     f    15     sam
```

You definitely should read [Pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Thank you so Much it works with merge Now. I don't know why it does not before

Comment: @ShahineGreene, glad I could help. Next time you have a question, read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

file1.csv

```
customer_id,sex,age,name
af4wf3,m,12,mike
z20ask,f,15,sam
```

file2.csv

```
transaction_id,customer_id,amount
12h2j4hk,af4wf3,123.20
12h2j4h1,af4wf3,5.22
12h2j4h2,z20ask,13.20
12h2j4h3,af4wf3,1.20
12h2j4h4,z20ask,2341.12
12h2j4h5,z20ask,235.96
12h2j4h6,af4wf3,999.30
```

Load and join the dataframes

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

df1.set_index('customer_id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('transaction_id', inplace=True)

output = df2.join(df1, on='customer_id')
output.to_csv('file2_updated.csv')
```

file2_updated.csv

```
transaction_id,customer_id,amount,sex,age,name
12h2j4hk,af4wf3,123.2,m,12,mike
12h2j4h1,af4wf3,5.22,m,12,mike
12h2j4h2,z20ask,13.2,f,15,sam
12h2j4h3,af4wf3,1.2,m,12,mike
12h2j4h4,z20ask,2341.12,f,15,sam
12h2j4h5,z20ask,235.96,f,15,sam
12h2j4h6,af4wf3,999.3,m,12,mike
```

Comment: thank you for this code , I tried to re_use  it : this message appears : "You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

Comment: It works if I st the index to another column

Comment: when I set  both index to Costumer_id : a message appears : olumns overlap but no suffix specified